# Magento 2 - Change value in .less file of a third party module

Tags: module, overrides, less, extend, styles

I need to change a value in this file of a 3rd party module from my own theme:

```
vendor/amasty/xsearch/view/frontend/web/css/source/module/components/_search-input.less
```

Am I correct that I need to make a 1:1 copy of that file in my theme and make my changes there?
Or can I just change the specific styles I need to change?

I put an exact copy of that file here:

```
app/design/frontend/company/name-of-theme/Amasty_Xsearch/web/css/source/module/components/_search-input.less
```

and made my changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it myself and I figured out, that you have to copy the whole file even if you just want to make some little changes, because you basically override the whole file by copying it into your theme.

You should also override these files, even if you want to only make small changes. This will make updates easier.

**Sidenote**: I noticed that you can't override **web/css/source/module/_base.less**